# Array size counting – Android, Java

Tags: java, android, arrays, cycle

I have been sitting whole day with this problem:

I have a String array.After parsing String line

```
str3.split("\\n"));
```

Then I want to make it display with Next/Previous buttons.

String text = null;

```
    if (rotation){

        if (count < fullString.length) {

            for (int i = count; i <= fullString.length - 1; i++) {
                text = fullString[i];
                ++count;
                if (text.trim().length() > 0 & !text.isEmpty()){
                    return text;

                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (!rotation) {

        if (count > 0) {
            for (int i = count ; i >= 0; i--) {
                text = fullString[i - 1];
                --count;
                if (text.trim().length() > 0 & !text.isEmpty()){
                    return text;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

It woks, but need to press button twise (If press "Next" after that I should press "Previous" twise).
I know, this is the silly question, but I can't find out the problem.

Comment: Why are you decreasing and increasing count twice?

Comment: Also, the second access to `fullString` in the code may go out of bounds (the last iteration is having `i=0` and you use index `i-1`.

Comment: It would help to know what are the buttons supposed to do, if you want a more comprehensive answer ...

Comment: @Mifeet, No, it doesn't

Comment: @whisperofblood It just hasn't so far.

Comment: I don't think you need both of your tests for emptiness, the test with `trim().length() > 0` contains `!isEmtpy()`.

Comment: @Joffrey Ok, but it isn't case of problem.

Comment: @whisperofblood Less code, less coding mistakes. Moreover, it would save time for readers of your code, especially readers of this post, thus making it easier to spot a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're not consistent with the meaning you give to `count` inside your loops.

### Possible meanings for `count`

#### 1. `count` represents the next item, the one that you want to return.

In this case your loops should start at `count+1` and `count-1`, respectively, and should both use `fullString[i]`.

#### 2. **`count` represents the current selected item, and you want the next.**

In this case your loops should both start at `count` and you should reference `fullString[i+1]` (first loop) or `fullString[i-1]` (second loop). You'll also have to be careful to **change the end condition** of your loops, so that `i+1` and `i-1` are not out of bounds.

### Current problem: mixed approaches

In the current state of your code, you mix both approaches:

- In the first loop, you start at `count` but use `fullString[i]`. Making one press on the button useless because you don't increment count right away.
- In the second loop, you use the second option without changing the end condition. This will trigger an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException` when `count` is 0 (or you don't find a non-empty string before index 0), as @Mifeet pointed out in a comment you decided to ignore.

### Improvement

Also, since you increment/decrement `count` anyway, I would use it directly instead of adding an index `i`. This makes your loops cleaner, and you can also get rid of the `if` on count.

```
if (rotation) {
    for (count++; count <= fullString.length - 1; count++) {
        text = fullString[count];
        if (text.trim().length() > 0) {
            return text;
        }
    }
}

if (!rotation) {
    for (count--; count >= 0; count--) {
        text = fullString[count];
        if (text.trim().length() > 0) {
            return text;
        }
    }
}
```